Home directory missing in Docker container launched by Jenkins (Jenkins uses its own OS user in container)
I am just setting up Jenkins as a CI/build system on a host. Some pipelines would use Docker container for the build process. Jenkins itself is installed on the host system (so no Docker-in-Docker scenario!).
TL;DR:
Jenkins would "inject" the OS-Jenkins user into the Docker build container. Since the OS-Jenkins user is not known in the container, this leads to several difficulties. One of them: the executing user in the container has no HOME directory.
Problems arising:

manual "git clone" commands in the build process would fail.
npm install does not work
pip install does not work

In more detail:
If you have a Jenkinsfile like this:
node {
    docker.image("bitnami/minideb:latest").inside() {
        echo "I am ..."
        sh "id"
    }
}


The Jenkins docker plugin would start the container with:
docker run -t -d -u 114:121 -w ...... bitnami/minideb:latest


Thus, it uses the local OS Jenkins user (happens to be UID 114 in my case) in the container. Since this user is not known in the container, it has e.g. no HOME directory.
Later in the build process, I need to execute
conan config install git@code.repo.server.com:group/tools/conan.git

Nevermind that you might not know conan - conan it is a dependency manager for C++. The only important thing here is that this above command would fetch conan settings from a repo and try to store the setting in a folder ~/.conan. AND it does some "git clone" commands on its own when trying to resolve the dependencies.
I think where it stucks is when conan tries to perform manual "git clone" steps.
It tried to boil it down:
#!groovy

def docker_image = "cr.myownrepos.com/group/proj1/prj/algotest-launcher:1.6"

node {
    docker.withRegistry('https://cr.myownrepo.com/', '78e560d3-73d7-4f36-a884-3001a913b202'){
        docker.image(docker_image).inside() {

            stage('Build') {
                sshagent(['my_sshKey']) {
                    sh "export HOME=/tmp"
                    sh "git clone git@cr.myownrepo.com:bmd-se/group/conan.git"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

So this is only a "git clone". Result: FAILURE with this output:
+ git clone git@code.siemens.com:bmd-se/tools/conan.git
Cloning into 'conan'...
No user exists for uid 114
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

In this case I cannot use the Jenkins git plugin instead, since the git command would be executed by the "conan" lib on its own.
Another aspect: npm install not possible
The same problem with npm install:
+ pip install tomli
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting tomli
  Downloading tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Installing collected packages: tomli
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.

Without HOME dir, no user-local npm install possible. And being non-root (UID 141), a global install is also not possible (insufficient privilges).
So my question(s):
How can I provide a "normal" user from the container's point of view, with a HOME directory and the ability to save something in it? I could define a default user in the Dockerfile, but Jenkins would simply ignore it and use the Jenkins OS user instead (hardcoding, as it seems).
Maybe the problem simply boils down to:
How can I manually do a "git clone somerepo" in a container launched by Jenkins docker plugin (when Jenkins injects a non-existent user with UID 114 into the container?
Update: forget about conan - the essence of the problem is that:

Jenkins would always launch a container as Jenkins OS user - which does not exist in the container
being non-root, no global changes in the container are possible (e.g.  pip install)
having no HOME dir, no local installation is possible in many cases (e.g. pip)

If I override Jenkins behavior with:
docker.image(docker_image).inside("-u root") {

I can circumvent "missing privileges", but:

this is not a non-root container anymore (obviously)
git would complain about "dubious ownership" because the source code injected by Jenkins would not be owned by root

sigh!
So how would a non-root container be used with Jenkins?

If that's a build tool – it's not part of the source code that changes with every commit – can you build it into your base image, rather than dynamically cloning it every time you run the container?

Yes conan is a build tool. Conan itself - as a tool - is already installed in the image (thus, "baked in"). But during the build process, the tool would dynamically fetch dependencies from various repos. These are dependencies of "my" product to be built, not dependencies of the tool itself. So I cannot "build them" into the image in advance. Think of conan being something like "pip" or "npm" ... These dependencies can indeed change from commit to commit.

Jenkins already knows to bind-mount the workspace directory into the container.  Can you run these checkouts in the main pipeline code, outside a container?  You also might be able to pass a -e HOME=... option when you start the container, in the .inside() call.

May be possible. But seems to be very unelegant - this would mean, I have to keep a "conan" or "pip" tool on the Jenkins host in sync with the conan/pip client in the container, to avoid incompatibilities. Seems awkward and fragile ...? BTW: "pip" has the same problem. I updated my original question ... No conan question anymore but a "how to use a non-root container with Jenkins?"
